# Replace text using an array of placeholder : replacement pairs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

This is a simple problem (I am new to JavaScript and have a limited knowledge of the syntax and using arrays etc.), so I am sure someone more knowledgeable will be able to advise the simplest solution fairly easily!

I would like to replace a number of text placeholders in an existing Google Doc template with variable text inputs, which I ultimately plan to populate from one or more external sources via APIs (such as a form).

```
  function replaceAllPlaceholders() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody(); //defines the range within which to replace text

  body.replaceText('placeholder1', 'replacement1');
  body.replaceText('placeholder2', 'replacement2');
  body.replaceText('placeholder3', 'replacement3');
  // ...
  body.replaceText('placeholder98', 'replacement98');
  body.replaceText('placeholder99', 'replacement99'); }
```

Rather than repeat the *replaceText(* function for each replacement as I have done above, how can I instead layout the information out as an array of placeholder:replacement pairs, and then loop through each?

```
// for example something like this (pseudo):
//
//    var obj = {
//    'placeholder1': 'replacement1' // I would like to keep open the option to retrieve this array from an external source instead
//    'placeholder2': 'replacement2'
//    'placeholder3': 'replacement3' };
//
//    body.replaceText(*all placeholders*,*all replacements*);
```

I imagine this would allow greater flexibility in editing the set of placeholders and or replacements going forward, either directly within Google Apps Script or by replacing the whole array to one retrieved from an external source (as well as reducing the code required). The problem is I have not been able to figure out the correct method to do this. Any suggestions?

Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve my goal?
I am open to all recommendations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var placeholders = [
  ['placeholder1', 'replacement1'],
  ['placeholder2', 'replacement2'],
  ['placeholder3', 'replacement3']
];

placeholders.forEach(function(pair) {
  body.replaceText(pair[0], pair[1]);
});
```